# What real experimental systems are well-described by Glauber-Ising spins?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

I'm hoping for references to actual physical systems in which all or at least most of the following can be simultaneously characterized: the spin flip rate, the temperature, and a relaxation or similar timescale. I'm also specifically looking for Glauber vs Kawasaki or some other dynamics. Isolated spins are especially interesting to me; spin glasses are not.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last statement (isolated spins vs. spin glasses)? Are the continuum generalizations (models A/B/etc) of interest to you, or do you mean to specifically ask about discrete systems?

Comment: Single or finite numbers of spins are what I would be most interested in. Spin glasses are not interesting because there is not really a single timescale or temperature beyond mean field.

Comment: The Ising model is a model of many interacting spins. Why would we expect it to apply to an isolated spin?

Comment: @d_b Perhaps there is some single dipole out there that obeys Glauber dynamics

Answer (score 1):

One can study the spin obervables, change in temperature and relaxation dynamics of [a coupled LMG model](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.02232), which has a spin repressentation. The low energy states are characterised by Glauber coherent states (the relation is given by a [Holstein-Primakoff mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holstein%E2%80%93Primakoff_transformation)). Here is a more [detailed thesis](https://scholar.sun.ac.za/handle/10019.1/106032) in case the referenced paper is not detailed enough. I should mention that the isolated system case is goten by just setting the coupling to zero.

Comment: This is a theoretical model, not an observation of a real system.

Comment: @d_b So the OP is asking for an experimental study of the described quantities? I ask, because there are countless realizations of the LMG model, as such it does describe many "actual physical systems".